# Premature end of file in Play controller unit test

Tags: xml, scala, playframework, specs2

I'm writing a new Scala Play 2.6 web service, and trying to write a unit test for a controller that accepts XML payloads. When I call the controller from the unit test, however, I get a 400 returned from the body parser (code doesn't get into the controller method body at all), and the error message says `For request 'PUT /series/97234752' [Invalid XML: Premature end of file.]`. The XML being parsed is valid, and I've tested it by even loading in a string of very simple XML that results in the same error. I've read that the issue could have to do with the bodyparser trying to read from a stream that's already been read, but I can't figure out how to do it properly (if that's the issue).

Here is the unit test code:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SeriesControllerSpec(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {
  val coreApi = mock[CoreApiService]
  val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(bind[CoreApiService].toInstance(coreApi)).build

  "SeriesController#save" should {
    "save a valid series in core-api and return the full model upon success" in new WithApplication(app) {
      val body = XML.load(getClass.getResource("/SeriesControllerSpec/valid_series.xml"))
      val coreApiResponse = Series(
        epgContentSourceId = "",
        seriesId = Some("54321"),
        partnerSeriesId = "97234752",
        seriesTexts = Set(
          LocalizedTextField(content = "English Title", field = "title", `type` = "full", lang = "en"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "Brief English Title", field = "title", `type` = "brief", lang = "en"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "English Sort Title", field = "title", `type` = "sort", lang = "en"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "English Description", field = "description", `type` = "full", lang = "en"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "Brief English Description", field = "description", `type` = "brief", lang = "en"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "Spanish Title", field = "title", `type` = "full", lang = "es"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "Brief Spanish Title", field = "title", `type` = "brief", lang = "es"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "Spanish Sort Title", field = "title", `type` = "sort", lang = "es"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "Spanish Description", field = "description", `type` = "full", lang = "es"),
          LocalizedTextField(content = "Brief Spanish Description", field = "description", `type` = "brief", lang = "es")
        ),
        genres = Set(Genre(genre = "documentary", `type` = Some("nielsen"))),
        categories = Set(Category(name = "original", `type` = None), Category(name = "Europe > UK > Manchester", `type` = Some("location"))).toSet
      )

      coreApi.saveSeries(any[Series]) returns Future(coreApiResponse, true)

      val controller = app.injector.instanceOf[SeriesController]
      val result = controller.save("97234752")(FakeRequest(method = "PUT", path = "/series/97234752").withHeaders(("Content-Type", "application/xml")).withXmlBody(body))

      val res = Await.result(result.run(), 1 second)

      res must be_===(Created(""))
    }
  }
}
```

And here's (part) of the controller:

```
class SeriesController @Inject()(coreApi: CoreApiService)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends XmlController {
  def save(seriesId: String) = Action.async(parse.xml) { request =>
    // execution never reaches in here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using in your controller a `parse.body`. When your are going to use one parser from PlayBodyParsers like `parse.xml`; you have to use the method `play.api.test.Helpers.call` to get the result. The following is an example of the implementation:

Controller:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.xml.NodeSeq

@Singleton
class XmlController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  private final val requestMaxLength: Int = 99999

  def post: Action[NodeSeq] = Action(parse.xml(requestMaxLength)) { implicit request: Request[NodeSeq] =>
    Ok(request.body)
  }
}
```

Test:

```
package controllers

import akka.stream.Materializer
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers, OptionValues}
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice._
import play.api.http.{HeaderNames, MimeTypes}
import play.api.mvc.{AnyContentAsXml, ControllerComponents, Request, Result}
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.io.Source
import scala.xml.NodeSeq

class XmlControllerTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with GuiceOneAppPerTest with OptionValues with Injecting with HeaderNames {

  lazy val cc: ControllerComponents = inject[ControllerComponents]

  lazy implicit val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer

  "Post" should "create a valid xml" in {
    val xmlString: String = Source.fromResource("request.xml").getLines().mkString
    val xml: NodeSeq = scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmlString)
    val controller: XmlController = new XmlController(cc)

    val request: Request[AnyContentAsXml] = FakeRequest()
      .withMethod(POST)
      .withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> MimeTypes.XML)
      .withXmlBody(xml)

    val postResult: Future[Result] = call(controller.post, request)

    play.api.test.Helpers.call()

    status(postResult) should equal(OK)
    contentType(postResult).value should equal(MimeTypes.XML)
  }

}
```

The important line is:

> val postResult: Future[Result] = call(controller.post, request)

I hope this can fix your issue.